# Audit Logs for Environment Path Changes

Tags: windows, security, windows-server-2012, logging, windows-server-2012-r2

Something (or someone) keeps changing our environment path variables on several of our servers.  I have the Audit Policy (under local sec pol) set to Success, Failure for all but Process Tracking (which is just failure).  However, when changes are made to our environment path, I'm not able to find where the audit log of the change is being logged.

Can someone point me in the direction where I would find the path environment variable change log (or how to enable auditing for environment path changes, if not already)?

I'm on Windows Server 2012 Standard.

Answer (score 0):

The machine path variable is stored in the registry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path
```

user variables are under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

To audit objects in Windows to have to do two things.

First turn auditing on, which you already did.

it should be enough to enable: `Success` for `Audit object access`

Secondly, you have to change the object which you want to audit.

In regedit.exe navigate to the key mentioned above.

Select `Permissions` from the `Edit` menu. Click the `Advanced` button and then the `Auditing` tab.

Click the `Add` button and then the `Select a principal` link, type `Everyone` and click `OK`.

Tick `Full Control` and three times `OK`

Now access to that registry key is audited. To look at the audit you use the `Security` log in `Event Viewer`

It should tell you: user, process, time and even the new value.

When you don't need the auditing anymore, you should turn it off again.